# nested if else statement being skipped and does nothing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, if-statement, barcode

I'm doing an app where the code will scan a barcode and check the content and if the content tally with the if else statement it will display the price. How do i solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
public class barcode extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button scan_btn;
    EditText Edit_current;
    TextView formatTxt, contentTxt,price;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_promotion_page);
        formatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanFormat);
        contentTxt = (TextView) findViewById(scanContent);
        price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Price);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(result.getContents( ) == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (result.getContents().equals(12345014)){

            price.setText("$999");
            }else if (result.getContents().equals(12345021)){

                price.setText("$91");

            }


        }}
```

Comment: You want to read about **switch** statements; and how to use them with strings for example.

Comment: It is skipped because none of the 3 conditions you specified is met. So result.getContents() is neither null, nor equal to 12345014 or 12345021

Comment: first you need to debug what is returned by getContents() method

Comment: As @AbdulWaheed said, try logging `result.getContents()`.
Also, switch case statements with a default saying "Item not found" would be better in your case, it would also be easier to add new items.

In your case, try adding an else block, with `price.setText("Item not found!")`

Comment: when i debugged the settext is not being called out

Comment: i actually wanted to use ean_13 barcode format for scaning but since android studio only supports 32, im limmited to use ean_8

Comment: na na you don't need to debug setText(), but debug this part of code if(result.getContents( ) == null) 
check what is returned by result.getContents()

Comment: it detedted format is eaan_8 and contents is 12345041

Comment: What type does result.getContents() return ?

Comment: type of barcode ? EAN_8

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information available, I believe it's because `result.getContents()` does not match any of the statements you're checking for. I'd add this as a final statement at the bottom:

```
} else {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Failed to match. Contents are " + result.getContents());
}
```

So at least you can see what `result.getContents()` contains, and can act accordingly. Your current solution is also not very scalable - I'd look into using `switch` statements or using SQLite to query a product database.

Comment: added this and eventhough i scan the content it doesnt show anything

Comment: That means that `onActivityResult()` is not being called at all then. Can you stick a `Log` line at the top of `onActivityResult()` just to make sure of this?